# Newly added layer has incorrect and seemingly unfixable data source

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, layer-file

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2. I added a layer to arc map and the layer loaded with the red exclamation mark next to it, indicating that it could not find the layer. I checked the data source and it was in a drive that the computer does not even have.

I have tried:

- Changing the data source from the properties and right click/data/repair data source
- removing the layer and re-adding it
- Re-downloading and reading the layer

The layer is the 2007 25m raster of the Center for Ecology and Hydrology Land Cover Map. The 1990 raster has the same problem. My download is missing the 2000 raster. The 1km raster works fine. I downloaded it from digimap, to which my university has a subscription.

Comment: @DanC - That would have to be a Layer **Package** not a Layer File. A Layer File is only going to contain a pointer to the data source and some misc info on how that data is to be displayed by ArcMap. A Layer File has no actual data (Feature Class, Shapefile or Raster) embedded in it.

Comment: @user23715 Thanks, you're right. New comment: I don't know the answer exactly, but I've been given layer packages (.LPK files) before that didn't actually include the source data. There's nothing wrong on your end, the file was created incorrectly. The data source you're seeing is the path to the data on the computer of the person who created the layer package. It sounds like this is data you're (indirectly) paying for, so I'd get in touch with the data provider.